# MySQL Not Using Index when Specifying Non-Indexed Columns

Tags: mysql

When trying to run a query specifying a non-indexed column or *, the index isn't used. Using the indexed column or count(*) does use the index. Any idea why specifying any non-indexed column in the output would case the index to not be used? I've noticed that as the number of rows increases, my queries have been slowing down.

Here are three identical queries where one uses count(*), the other just uses * and one uses an indexed column.

Optimized query

```
MariaDB [db]> explain select count(*) from data_history where id=18 and time > date_sub(now(), interval 7 day)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: data_history
         type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY,ID
          key: ID
      key_len: 26
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1176921
        Extra: Using where; Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Non-optimized query

```
MariaDB [db]> explain select * from data_history where id=18 and time > date_sub(now(), interval 7 day)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: data_history
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY,ID
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1176929
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Optimized query

```
MariaDB [db]> explain select id from data_history where id=18 and time > date_sub(now(), interval 7 day)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: data_history
         type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY,ID
          key: ID
      key_len: 26
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1176935
        Extra: Using where; Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `data_history` (
  `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `b1` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`time`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`id`,`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: `id` is defined as `varchar(20)`. in your WHERE-clause you should surround 18 with single quotes, like: `where id='18' and .... `

Comment: Both the `COUNT(*)` and `id` queries have `ID` listed for `key` in the explain plan. My guess would be that, given that the count doesn't need to fetch any other columns it can simply operate on the indexed id, whereas selecting all columns wouldn't offset any advantage the index could give.

Comment: Leaving my comment for posterity, but @Luuk is totally right. I've mocked up your scenario and running the `EXPLAIN` adds some warnings explaining the reason why the indices aren't used. Try checking the output of `SHOW WARNINGS\G` after running the explain.

Comment: @msbit: i should have added the info about show warnings....

Comment: @Luuk was correct. Surrounding with single quotes fixed this. Thanks!